# Scalability and availability

Tags: c#, scalability, high-availability

I am quite confused on which approach to take and what is best practice.
Lets say i have a C# application which does the following:

sends emails from a queue. Emails to send and all the content is stored in the DB.

Now, I know how to make my C# application almost scalable but I need to go somewhat further.

I want some form of responsibility of being able to distribute the tasks across say X servers. So it is not just 1 server doing all the processing but to share it amoungst the servers. 
If one server goes down, then the load is shared between the other servers. I know NLB does this but im not looking for an NLB here.

Sure, you could add a column of some kind in the DB table to indicate which server should be assigned to process that record, and each of the applications on the servers would have an ID of some kind that matches the value in the DB and they would only pull their own records - but this I consider to be cheap, bad practice and unrealistic.

Having a DB table row lock as well, is not something I would do due to potential deadlocks and other possible issues.

I am also NOT indicating using threading "to the extreme" here but yes, there will be threading per item to process or batching them up per thread for x amount of threads.

How should I approach and what do you recommend on making a C# application which is scalable and has high availability? The aim is to have X servers, each with the same application and for each to be able to get records and process them but have the level of processing/items to process shared amoungst the servers so incase if one server or service fails, the other can take on that load until another server is put back.

Sorry for my lack of understanding or knowledge but have been thinking about this quite alot and had lack of sleep trying to think of a good robust solution.

Comment: I would be thinking of batching up the work, so each app only pulled back x number of records at a time, marking those retrieved records as taken with a bool field in the table. I'd amend the the SELECT statement to pull only records not marked as taken/done. Table locks would be ok in this instance for very short periods to ensure there is no overlap of apps processing the same records.

Comment: Thanks Tom but thats what I want to avoid. For example, if the service takes x amount of records and marks them as "in progress", then during that processing it crashes....then those records are never out of the "in progress" state. I dont want this problem to occur. To also think that ANOTHER "monitor" service should be looking at the table to see if a record has been processed or not by x hours is also very poor design and more maintainence headache.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, if you're going to shoot down every possible solutions as “poor design”, you're not going to get very far.

Comment: lol. i know what you mean but im looking for something robust. im not shooting every solution down but im finding problems with it.... it just wouldnt be fit for purpose at all. what solutions do you have? the comments ive posted are perfectly valid and are not meant in a disrespectful way at all. im talking about enterprise type scalability and availability. how would you get out of the situation of a service select x records and marking them "in progress"  then half way through the server crashes? how can you recover really? you cant, not entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I would be thinking of batching up the work, so each app only pulled back x number of records at a time, marking those retrieved records as taken with a bool field in the table. I'd amend the the SELECT statement to pull only records not marked as taken/done. Table locks would be ok in this instance for very short periods to ensure there is no overlap of apps processing the same records.

**EDIT:** It's not very elegant, but you could have a datestamp and a status for each entry (instead of a bool field as above). Then you could run a periodic Agent job which runs a sproc to reset the status of any records which have a status of In Progress but which have gone beyond a time threshold without being set to complete. They would be ready for reprocessing by another app later on.

This may not be enterprise-y enough for your tastes, but I'd bet my hide that there are plenty of apps out there in the enterprise which are just as un-sophisticated and work just fine. The best things work with the least complexity.